# How to config webdriver version (no local path setter)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Chrome 65.0.3325.181 and I need ChromeDriver **2.36 or more**.

I use `selenium-java` and `selenium-server` (`org.seleniumhq.selenium`) 3.11.0

**Java code:**

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

**Console:**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a) on port 27329
Only local connections are allowed.
avr. 01, 2018 12:57:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFOS: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

**If I use a local binary driver it works but I do not use this workaround.**

```
OperatingSystem currentOperatingSystem = OperatingSystem.getCurrentOperatingSystem();
String pathWebdriver = String.format("src/test/resources/drivers/%s/googlechrome/%s/chromedriver%s", currentOperatingSystem.getOperatingSystemDir(),
         SystemArchitecture.getCurrentSystemArchitecture().getSystemArchitectureName(), currentOperatingSystem.getSuffixBinary());    
if (!new File(pathWebdriver).setExecutable(true)) {
    logger.error("ERROR when change setExecutable on " + pathWebdriver);
}
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathWebdriver);
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

console:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) on port 21006
Only local connections are allowed.
avr. 01, 2018 13:51:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFOS: Detected dialect: OSS
```

Comment: Setting path in environment variable `path` will work. When executing Java looks for the files in the directory path set by property OR the directory paths set in Path environment variable. https://developers.thomsonreuters.com/sites/default/files/How%20To%20Add%20ChromeDriver%20To%20System%20Variables_0.pdf

Comment: Why aren't you using the workaround if it works so well?

Comment: @ThomasTimbul, I do not just want to. I do not want to provide the driver. the user of my code is using chromedriver.

Comment: Then could you ask them to update their driver? Otherwise, if this applies only to your own testing, you could place Chromedriver on your own machine in the [default location](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver). That way you will have the latest used on your machine without having to program its use explicitly.